# Pine script combine 2 rsi (relative strength index) into 1 script

Tags: pine-script

i want to combine 2 rsi (relative strength index) into 1 script.
actually i have to use 2 rsi script in trading view with length 25 and 100.
so if there is any way to combine 2 setting into 1 so it can show 2 line in chart.

here i try to change rsi name but it's making same line twice. is the any way to fix my issue?

here is the code.

```
indicator(title="Relative Strength Index", shorttitle="RSI", format=format.price, precision=2, timeframe="", timeframe_gaps=true)

ma(source, length, type) =>
    switch type
        "SMA" => ta.sma(source, length)
        "Bollinger Bands" => ta.sma(source, length)
        "EMA" => ta.ema(source, length)
        "SMMA (RMA)" => ta.rma(source, length)
        "WMA" => ta.wma(source, length)
        "VWMA" => ta.vwma(source, length)

rsiLengthInput = input.int(25, minval=1, title="RSI Length", group="RSI Settings")
rsiSourceInput = input.source(close, "Source", group="RSI Settings")
maTypeInput = input.string("SMA", title="MA Type", options=["SMA", "Bollinger Bands", "EMA", "SMMA (RMA)", "WMA", "VWMA"], group="MA Settings")
maLengthInput = input.int(14, title="MA Length", group="MA Settings")
bbMultInput = input.float(2.0, minval=0.001, maxval=50, title="BB StdDev", group="MA Settings")

up = ta.rma(math.max(ta.change(rsiSourceInput), 0), rsiLengthInput)
down = ta.rma(-math.min(ta.change(rsiSourceInput), 0), rsiLengthInput)
rsi = down == 0 ? 100 : up == 0 ? 0 : 100 - (100 / (1 + up / down))
rsiMA = ma(rsi, maLengthInput, maTypeInput)
isBB = maTypeInput == "Bollinger Bands"

plot(rsi, "RSI 1", color=#00d812)

rsiUpperBand = hline(70, "RSI Upper Band", color=#787B86)
hline(50, "RSI Middle Band", color=color.new(#787B86, 50))
rsiLowerBand = hline(30, "RSI Lower Band", color=#787B86)
fill(rsiUpperBand, rsiLowerBand, color=color.rgb(126, 87, 194, 90), title="RSI Background Fill")
bbUpperBand = plot(isBB ? rsiMA + ta.stdev(rsi, maLengthInput) * bbMultInput : na, title = "Upper Bollinger Band", color=color.green)
bbLowerBand = plot(isBB ? rsiMA - ta.stdev(rsi, maLengthInput) * bbMultInput : na, title = "Lower Bollinger Band", color=color.green)
fill(bbUpperBand, bbLowerBand, color= isBB ? color.new(color.green, 90) : na, title="Bollinger Bands Background Fill")


/////////////  2nd rsi  ///////////////

ma1(source, length, type) =>
    switch type
        "SMA" => ta.sma(source, length)
        "Bollinger Bands1" => ta.sma(source, length)
        "EMA1" => ta.ema(source, length)
        "SMMA (RMA)1" => ta.rma(source, length)
        "WMA1" => ta.wma(source, length)
        "VWMA1" => ta.vwma(source, length)

rsiLengthInput1 = input.int(100, minval=1, title="RSI Length", group="RSI Settings")
rsiSourceInput1 = input.source(close, "Source", group="RSI Settings")
maTypeInput1 = input.string("SMA1", title="MA Type", options=["SMA1", "Bollinger Bands", "EMA", "SMMA (RMA)", "WMA", "VWMA"], group="MA Settings")
maLengthInput1 = input.int(14, title="MA Length", group="MA Settings")
bbMultInput1 = input.float(2.0, minval=0.001, maxval=50, title="BB StdDev", group="MA Settings")

up1 = ta.rma(math.max(ta.change(rsiSourceInput), 0), rsiLengthInput)
down1 = ta.rma(-math.min(ta.change(rsiSourceInput), 0), rsiLengthInput)
rsi1 = down == 0 ? 100 : up == 0 ? 0 : 100 - (100 / (1 + up / down))
rsiMA1 = ma(rsi, maLengthInput, maTypeInput)
isBB1 = maTypeInput == "Bollinger Bands"

plot(rsi1, "RSI 2", color=#010a02)

rsiUpperBand1 = hline(70, "RSI Upper Band", color=#787B86)
hline(50, "RSI Middle Band", color=color.new(#787B86, 50))
rsiLowerBand1 = hline(30, "RSI Lower Band", color=#787B86)
fill(rsiUpperBand, rsiLowerBand, color=color.rgb(126, 87, 194, 90), title="RSI Background Fill")
bbUpperBand1 = plot(isBB ? rsiMA + ta.stdev(rsi, maLengthInput) * bbMultInput : na, title = "Upper Bollinger Band", color=color.green)
bbLowerBand1 = plot(isBB ? rsiMA - ta.stdev(rsi, maLengthInput) * bbMultInput : na, title = "Lower Bollinger Band", color=color.green)
fill(bbUpperBand, bbLowerBand, color= isBB ? color.new(color.green, 90) : na, title="Bollinger Bands Background Fill")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't change all your variable name to ..1 in the second part, here is the corrected code :

```
//@version=5
indicator(title="Relative Strength Index", shorttitle="RSI", format=format.price, precision=2, timeframe="", timeframe_gaps=true)

ma(source, length, type) =>
    switch type
        "SMA" => ta.sma(source, length)
        "Bollinger Bands" => ta.sma(source, length)
        "EMA" => ta.ema(source, length)
        "SMMA (RMA)" => ta.rma(source, length)
        "WMA" => ta.wma(source, length)
        "VWMA" => ta.vwma(source, length)

rsiLengthInput = input.int(25, minval=1, title="RSI Length", group="RSI Settings")
rsiSourceInput = input.source(close, "Source", group="RSI Settings")
maTypeInput = input.string("SMA", title="MA Type", options=["SMA", "Bollinger Bands", "EMA", "SMMA (RMA)", "WMA", "VWMA"], group="MA Settings")
maLengthInput = input.int(14, title="MA Length", group="MA Settings")
bbMultInput = input.float(2.0, minval=0.001, maxval=50, title="BB StdDev", group="MA Settings")

up = ta.rma(math.max(ta.change(rsiSourceInput), 0), rsiLengthInput)
down = ta.rma(-math.min(ta.change(rsiSourceInput), 0), rsiLengthInput)
rsi = down == 0 ? 100 : up == 0 ? 0 : 100 - (100 / (1 + up / down))
rsiMA = ma(rsi, maLengthInput, maTypeInput)
isBB = maTypeInput == "Bollinger Bands"

plot(rsi, "RSI 1", color=#00d812)

rsiUpperBand = hline(70, "RSI Upper Band", color=#787B86)
hline(50, "RSI Middle Band", color=color.new(#787B86, 50))
rsiLowerBand = hline(30, "RSI Lower Band", color=#787B86)
fill(rsiUpperBand, rsiLowerBand, color=color.rgb(126, 87, 194, 90), title="RSI Background Fill")
bbUpperBand = plot(isBB ? rsiMA + ta.stdev(rsi, maLengthInput) * bbMultInput : na, title = "Upper Bollinger Band", color=color.green)
bbLowerBand = plot(isBB ? rsiMA - ta.stdev(rsi, maLengthInput) * bbMultInput : na, title = "Lower Bollinger Band", color=color.green)
fill(bbUpperBand, bbLowerBand, color= isBB ? color.new(color.green, 90) : na, title="Bollinger Bands Background Fill")


/////////////  2nd rsi  ///////////////

ma1(source, length, type) =>
    switch type
        "SMA" => ta.sma(source, length)
        "Bollinger Bands1" => ta.sma(source, length)
        "EMA1" => ta.ema(source, length)
        "SMMA (RMA)1" => ta.rma(source, length)
        "WMA1" => ta.wma(source, length)
        "VWMA1" => ta.vwma(source, length)

rsiLengthInput1 = input.int(100, minval=1, title="RSI Length", group="RSI Settings")
rsiSourceInput1 = input.source(close, "Source", group="RSI Settings")
maTypeInput1 = input.string("SMA1", title="MA Type", options=["SMA1", "Bollinger Bands", "EMA", "SMMA (RMA)", "WMA", "VWMA"], group="MA Settings")
maLengthInput1 = input.int(14, title="MA Length", group="MA Settings")
bbMultInput1 = input.float(2.0, minval=0.001, maxval=50, title="BB StdDev", group="MA Settings")

up1 = ta.rma(math.max(ta.change(rsiSourceInput1), 0), rsiLengthInput1)
down1 = ta.rma(-math.min(ta.change(rsiSourceInput1), 0), rsiLengthInput1)
rsi1 = down1 == 0 ? 100 : up1 == 0 ? 0 : 100 - (100 / (1 + up1 / down1))
rsiMA1 = ma(rsi1, maLengthInput1, maTypeInput1)
isBB1 = maTypeInput1 == "Bollinger Bands"

plot(rsi1, "RSI 2", color.blue)

rsiUpperBand1 = hline(70, "RSI Upper Band", color=#787B86)
hline(50, "RSI Middle Band", color=color.new(#787B86, 50))
rsiLowerBand1 = hline(30, "RSI Lower Band", color=#787B86)
fill(rsiUpperBand, rsiLowerBand1, color=color.rgb(126, 87, 194, 90), title="RSI Background Fill")
bbUpperBand1 = plot(isBB1 ? rsiMA1 + ta.stdev(rsi1, maLengthInput1) * bbMultInput1 : na, title = "Upper Bollinger Band", color=color.green)
bbLowerBand1 = plot(isBB1 ? rsiMA1 - ta.stdev(rsi1, maLengthInput1) * bbMultInput1 : na, title = "Lower Bollinger Band", color=color.green)
fill(bbUpperBand1, bbLowerBand1, color= isBB1 ? color.new(color.green, 90) : na, title="Bollinger Bands Background Fill")
```

and the result on the chart:
[image]